# RadioButton Not Checked on Start

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, radio-button

I have an application with four radio buttons to select the mode I am operating.
All the 4 Radio Buttons are binded to the same property. When i start the program the none of the radio button is checked.

This is the code for the radio buttons:

```
    <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,10,10,10" FontSize="16" 
    FontWeight="Bold">
        <GroupBox.Header>Tipo di Rientro</GroupBox.Header>
        <StackPanel>
            <RadioButton Name="RdBtnExternalEntry" FontSize="12" 
            FontWeight="Normal" GroupName="SelectionType" IsChecked="{Binding 
            Path=CurrentOption, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource 
            enumConverter}, ConverterParameter=ExternalEntry}">Entrata da 
            Esterno</RadioButton>

            <RadioButton Name="RdBtnEntryAfterCheck" FontSize="12" 
            FontWeight="Normal" GroupName="SelectionType" IsChecked="{Binding 
            Path=CurrentOption, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource 
            enumConverter}, ConverterParameter=EntryAfterCheck}">Rientro dopo 
            visione</RadioButton>

            <RadioButton Name="RdBtnEntryMissingShipping" FontSize="12" 
            FontWeight="Normal" GroupName="SelectionType" IsChecked="{Binding 
            Path=CurrentOption, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource 
            enumConverter}, ConverterParameter=EntryMissingShipping}">Rientro 
            per mancata Spedizione</RadioButton>

            <RadioButton Name="RdBtnEntryAfterPicking" FontSize="12" 
            FontWeight="Normal" GroupName="SelectionType" IsChecked="{Binding 
            Path=CurrentOption, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource 
            enumConverter}, ConverterParameter=EntryAfterPicking}">Rientro 
            dopo Picking</RadioButton>
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
```

This is the property:

```
public RadioOptions CurrentOption
        {
            get => _currentOption;
            set
            {
                _currentOption = value;
                NewLoadCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                ConfirmCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                if (value == RadioOptions.ExternalEntry)
                {
                    _selectedStockUnitCode = PalletToDo;
                    SelectedLoadnumber = LoadToDo;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedLoadnumber");
                    RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedStockUnitCode");
                }
                else
                {
                    SelectedLoadnumber = "0";
                    RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedLoadnumber");
                }

                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedStockUnitCodeIsEnabled");
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedLoadnumberIsEnabled");
            }
        }
```

And this is the converter:

```
public class EnumMatchToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null || parameter == null)
                return false;

            string checkValue = value.ToString();
            string targetValue = parameter.ToString();
            return checkValue.Equals(targetValue,
                     StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                                  object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null || parameter == null)
                return null;

            bool useValue = (bool)value;
            string targetValue = parameter.ToString();
            if (useValue)
                return Enum.Parse(targetType, targetValue);

            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }

    }
```

these are the radio options:

```
public enum RadioOptions { ExternalEntry, EntryAfterCheck, EntryMissingShipping, EntryAfterPicking }
```

I expect the first combobox to be checked at the start of the program

Comment: Why do you expect that? Nothing indicates that the value is ever changed.

Comment: _currentoption is not nullable so it start as the first value of the enum RadioOptions. On the start the program should use the get branch to update the radiobuttons.

Comment: Can you post your `RadioOptions`?

Comment: I tried your code and works as you expect. How do you set the DataContext on the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved! I was, by mistake launching another copy of my window as a popup istance messing up with the way xaml manages the radio buttons. I deleted one of the istance and then it worked fine.